# Getting this error while trying to fetch values with sql query in java springboot

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot

what is going wrong in this sql query?

I want to retrieve only externalId and externalIdType on the combination of patientId and channelId, this query is written in Repository class

And there can be multiple rows for same combintaion of patientId and channelID,

**Query**

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Transactional
@Query(value = "SELECT t.externalId, t.externalIdType FROM tb_patient_map t WHERE t.patientId = :patientId AND t.channelId = :channelId ", nativeQuery = true)
List<Oas2ChannelPatient> findByOasPatientIdAndChannelId(@Param("patientId") String patientId,@Param("channelId") int channelId);
```

getting this error

```
unexpected errororg.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Unable to find column position by name: channelPatientMapId; SQL [n/a]
```

**This is the DB structure**

```
channelPatientMapId PK,
patientId,
channelId,
externalId,
externalIdType,
createdAt,
createdBy
```

this is the dto class

```
public class ChannelPatientDto extends DetailBaseDto{
@Data
        public static class ChannelExternalIdDTO {
            private String externalId;
            private String externalIdType;

            public ChannelExternalIdDTO(String externalId,String externalIdType){
                this.externalId=externalId;
                this.externalIdType=externalIdType;

            }
        }
}
```

updated query : is this query correct?

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "SELECT NEW ChannelPatientSearchDto.ChannelExternalIdDTO(t.externalId, t.externalIdType) FROM tb_oas_2_channel_patient_map t WHERE t.oasPatientId = :oasPatientId AND t.channelId = :channelId ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<ChannelPatientSearchDto.ChannelExternalIdDTO> findByOasPatientIdAndChannelId(@Param("patientId") String patientId, @Param("channelId") int channelId);
```

Comment: You are creating a query and mapping the result to a JPA entity which requires the PK to be present. It isn't hence the failure. Also why the query and not just a query method or a JPA query instead? If you want to retrieve only those 2 columns write a dedicated DTO for this.

Comment: @Chaosfire I appolozise, it was my typo error, i have changed the actual name, variable names i have checked all are correct

Comment: @M.Deinum sounds correct, not only these 2 fields actually , i have other table which has to be retrive entirely, all col, so if using dto I need to use getter and setter, for so many fields, it doesnt seems to be right approach

Comment: Just write a JPA query which constructs the DTO. Use proper return types, imho returning an entity from a method that doesn't fully populate it is confusing and might lead to expectations.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have updated my dto and latest query in post, it is also not working can you help in reviewing it.

Comment: Your query is wrong. You cannot use JPQL features in a SQL query.